# запуск телеграм бота на windows server 2016

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot, telepot

При запуске бота в консоли вижу следующее:

```
 c:\Telegram>py bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 217, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 443, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot6618969731:AAFOBz3HXVVk8YNLeBAH8myEyzclfS8-yJI/getUpdates (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 217, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 443, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot6618969731:AAFOBz3HXVVk8YNLeBAH8myEyzclfS8-yJI/getUpdates (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telepot\api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 217, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 443, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SCT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot6618969731:AAFOBz3HXVVk8YNLeBAH8myEyzclfS8-yJI/getUpdates (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Telegram\bot.py", line 31, in <module>
    time.sleep(20)
```

Код бота:

```
    from tracemalloc import start
import telepot, time, subprocess

bot = telepot.Bot('token')

def remote(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

    if (content_type == 'text'):
        command = msg['text']
        print ('Got command: %s' % command)

        if '/start' in command:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Доступные команды: \nОтключить Rdp - /off \nВключить Rdp - /on \nАктивные сессии Rdp - /session")

        if '/off' in command:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/profile', '/user:a_ap@bam1', '/savecred', "powershell.exe Start-Process PowerShell C:\Telegram\dp_disable.ps1 -Verb RunAs"])           
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"RDP отключен")
        if '/on' in command: 
            p = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/profile', '/user:a_ap@bam1', '/savecred', "powershell.exe Start-Process PowerShell C:\Telegram\dp_enable.ps1 -Verb RunAs"])           
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"RDP включен")
        if '/session' in command:          
            output = subprocess.check_output(['runas', '/profile', '/user:a_ap@bam1', '/savecred', "powershell.exe Start-Process PowerShell C:\Telegram\query_session.ps1"])
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Активные сессии:', output)
            


bot.message_loop(remote)

while 1:
    time.sleep(20)
```